# How to validate json schema without using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema in c# Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, jsonschema, njsonschema

I have json schema and value to compare against it. I have implemented it using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema. But now realised that it is not for free use. I then tried to implement is using NJsonScehma nuget package but now getting the below error on last line of code.

> cannot convert from 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchema'

Below is my code. Any idea how to resolve this. TIA.

```
var jsonSchema = JObject.Parse(schemafile);  //schema definition
JToken json = JToken.Parse(value);//value to validate against schema
var result = jsonSchema.Validate(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

My validator, [JsonSchema.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonSchema.Net/), is built on System.Text.Json.  It's part of a larger suite called [`json-everything`](https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything).
You can read the docs [here](https://docs.json-everything.net/).

I'm also one of the authors of the JSON Schema spec.

Comment: I gone through it and I am confused which one to use. Can you please guide me according to my scenario. TIA.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by "which one to use"? I linked to the specific library on Nuget that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with [NJsonSchema](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema) with below code

```
var json = JsonSchema.FromJsonAsync(schemafile); 
var jsonSchema = json.Result;
JToken jsonValue = JToken.Parse(value);
var result = jsonSchema.Validate(jsonValue);
```